# SharePoint 2016 not able to create the column name with Restricted?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, list-definition

I was a created a Document Library all fields creating with no issues.

only problem with Restricted field name.

I was created a Restricted field as choice field but it was coming as lookup field.(see the attachement.)

this was happening only in 2016 site.
(Note: If i create the column manually with same name it was creating.
but i want to create by list definition)
[image]

Comment: Is there a Site Column named 'Restricted'?

Comment: With column name Restricted No site columns are present in site

Comment: Yep. Got caught out by this today. Legacy code that referenced a column by internal name 'Restricted'. We just changed it to 'IsRestricted' and modified our legacy code and all was swell.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a rather annoying "feature" in 2016. "Restricted" seems to be a new reserved keyword of some sort which causes issues due to naming conflicts. We just went through a large migration process which resulted in numerous apps failing because we were querying based on "Restricted" and specifying that field as viewfields and select parameters.. Now, the fields are all named Restricted0, cf00_Restricted, and other strange things.